# Show loading image while uploading files

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, file-upload, image-uploading

I'm submitting multipart/form-data form as shown below.
Here form is targeted to a iframe.

```
  <form id="upp" method="post" action="sample.jsp" name="upform" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="my_iframe">
     <input type="hidden" name="todo" value="upload">
     <input id="haa" type="file" name="uploadfile"  size="50">
  </form>

 <iframe id="my" name="my_iframe" scrolling="no" src="sample.jsp"  frameBorder="0">

  </iframe>
```

And script I used is

```
     $('#haa').change(function() {

         $('#upp').submit();

       });
```

Now how can I put loading image(.gif) while file is uploading to the iframe.

Comment: Iframes have a `load` event. Show the loading gif by default, then hide it when the iframe is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with a demo: http://www.itgeared.com/articles/1508-display-gif-loading-iframe-jquery/

What you need to enable is basically some javascript like

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#iframe1').on('load', function () {
        $('#loader1').hide();
    });
});
```

and some css which you hide after the content is loaded:

```
#loader1 {
    position:absolute;
    background:#ffffff;
}
```

you can replace the background color by any url(image...)